# CSS3 Webkit Full Screen Detection Not Working

Tags: html, css, webkit

I am having a really tuff time getting CSS3 to detect full screen. Right now, I have:

```
:-webkit-full-screen body {
    color: red;
    background: red;
}
```

When hitting F11 in my browser, nothing turns red.

For testing, I am trying to turn everything red but not having success. I am using **Chromium 31.0.1650.57**. Am I using `:-webkit-full-screen` incorrectly?

Comment: I tried the following: `:-webkit-full-screen *, :-moz-full-screen *, :fullscreen * {color: #f00!important;background: #f00!important;}` thinking that perhaps the `body` tag wasn't enough... I figured perhaps using the `*` may force it all... but it too failed.  Some documentation can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:fullscreen but it states that the technology is not widely supported and it is still experimental.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this has something to do with you pressing F11 to get fullscreen. You need to trigger the fullscreen via `webkitRequestFullscreen` and the other cross-browser versions of this. Also, I think that the CSS doesn't apply to the body.
Try to use a wrapper and apply it to that element:

```js
document.getElementById('gofullscreen').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
    elem.msRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

 :-webkit-full-screen #wrapper {
  color: red;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <a href="#" id="gofullscreen">fullscreen</a>
</div>
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7kPsL/12/) and [Fullscreen version](http://fiddle.jshell.net/7kPsL/12/show/light)
(Use the Fiddle link to see the code and the Fullscreen version to see it working, Fiddle doesn't allow fullscreen I think).

But the `:-webkit-full-screen` and the like are experimental, so don't rely on it.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode

Comment: Are you using http://jsfiddle.net/7kPsL/12/ or  http://fiddle.jshell.net/7kPsL/12/show/light. Via Fiddle itself it doesn't work. But the second URL does.

Comment: It looks like you are running elem.webkitRequestFullscreen(); twice in that code...once before the if block and one time inside the if block.  Am I reading that correctly?

Answer (score 1):

**Making an element go full-screen**

*Like this on some browser it may work*:

```
function gofullscreen() {
        var elem = document.getElementById("VideoWrapper");
        elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
        if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
            elem.requestFullscreen();
        } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
            elem.msRequestFullscreen();
        } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
            elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
        }
    }
$("#buttonGo").click(function(){gofullscreen()});

**//CSS**   

:-webkit-full-screen #VideoWrapper {
    color: red;
    background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

:-moz-full-screen #VideoWrapper {
    color: red;
    background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

:-ms-fullscreen #VideoWrapper {
    color: red;
    background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

:full-screen #VideoWrapper {
    color: red;
    background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

:fullscreen #VideoWrapper {
    color: red;
    background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

## On some browser it might not work

**To make it work across regardless of standard Css**

```
$("#buttonGo").click(function(){
$("#VideoWrapper").css({height: '100%',width:'100%',background:'red',color:'red'});
gofullscreen()});
```

This work well on chrome , ff , ms