# Browser F11 Fullscreen Does Not Register with -webkit-full-screen or Javascript API

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am using javascript(for example, `requestFullscreen`) and css(`:-webkit-full-screen`) API's to detect the browser's state in full screen or not. I don't have a issue with these API's, as they work successfully.

The issue I am having is that if the user hits <kbd>F11</kbd>, it does not register in the browser's environment and the javascript api and CSS api's for fullscreen detection do not detect fullscreen. Is there any way to work around this? I have some animations that depend on the size of the screen(in regards to fullscreen) and I have come to a dead end.

Comment: I am having similar issues. I can toggle fullscreen with custom JavaScript code, but as soon as a user starts using a combination of the F11 key + custom JavaScript code, all goes bad.

Comment: From [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21342259/2908724) it seems to be an unworkaroundable issue, though perhaps you can capture the F11 keypress event and do the necessary steps?

Comment: do you handle the key events ? because if you preventDefault / stopPropagation it could explain the issue.

Comment: @bishop, this was a good try. Unfortunately, F11 will not get captured unless the cursor clicked inside the viewport first.

Answer (score 3):

Worth a look

```
(function() {  

    var checktimer;

    function isFullScreen() {
        return (window.fullScreen) || (window.innerWidth == screen.width && window.innerHeight == screen.height);
    }

    $(window).on('resize', function() { 
        if(typeof checktimer!="undefined") { clearTimeout(checktimer); }
        checktimer = setTimeout(function() { alert(isFullScreen()); },2000); 
    });

})();
```

Notice that the call to the isFullScreen() function is timed, this is because some browsers will animate the fullscreen action , causing a resize event to fire until the animate stops.

Tried on Firefox and Chrome - ff uses the `window.fullScreen` here, I have not looked at the others, but easy enough to add those in the check of the return.

Comment: I have tried this before and window.innerHeight and screen.width do not change when F11 is pressed(nether is resized listener caught by F11).

Comment: Hi Dman, firefox might not, that is why  the check for window.fullscreen is included. Try it again ( I used the latest chrome and firefox to run this  )

Answer (score 2):

As @bigBen suggested in his comment above, `$(window).on('resize', function() {  });` does detect <kbd>F11</kbd>, for me too (Chrome Version 33.0.1750.154 m).

However, with the way I use it there are multiple calls because of the `on('keydown'/'keyup')`, so as long as you use `off('keydown'/'keyup')` right after, it'll run your functions once.*
**Correction* The multiple calls were because of `window.onresize`, not `keydown`.

Here's a console screenshot where I logged entering and exiting via <kbd>F11</kbd> using 'resize'
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ojr1.png

**Old** code:

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(event) {
    $(document).off('keydown');
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        if ($('body').hasClass('fullscreenOn')) {
            $('body').removeClass('fullscreenOn');
            // Do functions when exiting fullscreen
            $(document).on('keydown'); // Turn keydown back on after functions
            console.log("Exit F11");
        } else {
            $('body').addClass('fullscreenOn');
            // Do functions when entering fullscreen
            $(document).on('keydown'); // Turn keydown back on after functions
            console.log("Enter F11");
        }
    });
});
```

Jsfiddle (old): http://jsfiddle.net/4b8VL/ (Caveat - need to click inside result area before first <kbd>F11</kbd> keypress)

Using 'resize' has the added benefit of also detecting when entering fullscreen via JS API. Do note that if you're using fullscreen via JS API as well, you should hide the button for going fullscreen (via the JS API) whenever fullscreen is activated. Thus the user can only use the exit method given by the browser - <kbd>Esc</kbd> when fullscreen entered via JS API, or <kbd>F11</kbd> when fullscreen entered via <kbd>F11</kbd>.

*** Update *** The following code is cross-browser friendly. Instead of detecting window.onresize and using that as a basis for toggling fullscreen, it's better to just redirect the <kbd>F11</kbd> key to use the fullscreen API.

```
// fullscreen API goes here - **MDN - Using fullscreen mode -** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode

$(document).on('fullscreenchange', function(event) { // 'fullscreenchange' eventlistener from fullscreen API
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($('body').hasClass('fullscreen')) {
        $('body').removeClass('fullscreen');
        // Do functions when exiting fullscreen
        console.log("Exit Fullscreen");
    } else {
        $('body').addClass('fullscreen');
        // Do functions when entering fullscreen
        console.log("Enter Fullscreen");
    }
});

$(document).on('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.which == 122) {
        event.preventDefault();
        toggleFullScreen(); // From fullscreen API
    }
});
```

Note: This doesn't appear to work in jsfiddle, due to the way jsfiddle is setup, I believe . However, it works in live sites; check out a side project of mine at http://aaronkhare.com/playground/circa (*turn your volume down/off*) for a live, working example of the new code.

Comment: Yes, in when hitting F11 while in viewport. But if you click outside of view port on such as the browser toolbar and hit F11 the resize will not register.

Comment: When I click on the browser toolbar, or even hit F11 when in another tab and tab back to my webpage with this code, it still works, for me. Check out the added jsfiddle - Note however, it's not the best example due to the nature of a fiddle requiring you to click inside the result area first. If you view one of my sideprojects at http://aaronkhare.com/playground/circa/ (a video autoplays so turn off/down your sound) you'll see it works even in the situations you mentioned.

Comment: I've added another method, which is much better since it makes F11 tap into the JS API. Also, check out my side project linked above for a live example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use event listener **fullscreenchange** :

```
var isFullscreen = false;
document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', function () {
    isFullscreen = !!document.fullscreen;
    yourFunction();
}, false);

document.addEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', function () {
    isFullscreen = !!document.mozFullScreen;
    yourFunction();
}, false);

document.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', function () {
    isFullscreen = !!document.webkitIsFullScreen;
    yourFunction();
}, false);

function yourFunction() {
    if(isFullscreen) {
        $('.your-element').addClass('fullscreen');
        // ...
    } else {
        $('.your-element').removeClass('fullscreen');
        // ...
    }
}
```

Documentation:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:fullscreen
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/fullscreenchange

Comment: This is a good idea, unfortunately the eventlisteners do not detect the screen change if done by F11.

Comment: I guess that `$(window).on('resize', function() {  });` is not enough ?

Comment: No, because the F11 fullscreen will not trigger the event listener resize ether.

Comment: Doesn't it ? I've tried and It works on my lastest Firefox, Chrome, and MsIE.

Comment: I have used a event listener in chromium for resize and with F11 the event is not triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this HTML5 Enter Fullscreen shim:

A shim is like a mini hack to make the action cross browser compatible (really a wedge or doorjam), until the browsers figure it out

```
// detecting if browser supports fullscreen
return document.body.mozRequestFullScreen 
    || document.body.webkitRequestFullScreen 
    || document.body.requestFullScreen;

// requesting full screen on an elm
( elm.mozRequestFullScreen && elm.mozRequestFullScreen() ) 
    || ( elm.webkitRequestFullScreen && elm.webkitRequestFullScreen() ) 
    || ( elm.requestFullScreen && elm.requestFullScreen() );

    //binding to full screen event
    ( document.body.requestFullScreen && 
        window.addEventListener('fullscreenchange',fullScreenEvent) ) || ( document.body.webkitRequestFullScreen && 
        window.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange',fullScreenEvent ) ) || ( document.body.mozRequestFullScreen && 
        window.addEventListener('mozfullscreenchange',fullScreenEvent) );
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/samccone/1653975/raw/0c5597e6bc8e312d0674ff25a67d3271916a957f/gistfile1.js

Comment: That would work but the issue is 'addEventListener('fullscreenchange',...) will not catch the event if it is done by F11. I need to know the status of the full screen which will report falsely if the use has hit F11.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to listen for the F11 key being pressed, manually fire the fullscreen API requestFullscreen method, and return false:

```
// listen for fullscreenchange and keydown events
$(document).on({
    'fullscreenchange': fullscreenToggled,
    'keydown': documentKeydown
});

// if F11 has been pressed, call the fullscreen api requestFullscreen method
// and return false, disabling the default browser functionality
function documentKeydown(e) {
    if ( e.originalEvent.code == 'F11' ) {
        $('body')[0].requestFullscreen();
        return false;
    }
}

// check to see if body has the :fullscreen pseudo-class
// (which only gets detected when fullscreen is launched via the api)
function fullscreenToggled() {
    if ( $('body').is(':fullscreen') ) {
        // we are in fullscreen mode
    } else {
        // not in fullscreen mode
    }
}
```

Admittedly this won't work if the user launches fullscreen mode from the browser menu, and has not been tested in anything other than Chrome (v84.0.4147.125) at the moment, but does the job for me.